# Add document to collection in Cloud Firestore without overwrite previous document Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my flutter application I need to add document into a collection "influencerPost" and every time user adds a new "post" this document must be added to the previous... but in this moment I just get an overwrite of the previous document.
as you can see by my method, I have `uploadImage` future
which picked up image and store it to Storage in Firebase.
after that I create a collection called  `influencerPost` and I must add every time new post is generate new documents without overwrite

this is the full code:

```
Future uploadImage(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(_postImage.path);
    Reference firebaseStorageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('postImage/$fileName');
    UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_postImage);
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
    final String downloadUrl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('influencerPost')
        .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
        .set({
      "imageUrl": downloadUrl,
      'postText': IfUserProfile.post
    });
    setState(() => CircularProgressIndicator());
  }
```

In this way I get all but the documents are overwrite instead i need to keep the previous and add a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to maintain multiple post against user you have to create sub collection. Check below code where I have added sub collection .collection("post")

```
    Future uploadImage(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(_postImage.path);
    Reference firebaseStorageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('postImage/$fileName');
    UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_postImage);
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
    final String downloadUrl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('influencerPost')
        .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
        .collection("post")
        .add({
      "imageUrl": downloadUrl,
      'postText': IfUserProfile.post
    });
    setState(() => CircularProgressIndicator());
  }
```

Comment: thanks and to grab it from cloud firestore need to specify influencerPost/post path right?